# Отображения .txt в бразере без сохранения

Tags: tomcat

Помогите найти информацию по данному вопросу.

Есть `txt` файл, который создаётся и заменяется на новый каждый день. Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот файл отображался в самом браузере, но он выдаёт окно сохранения. Не знаю с чем это связано, но если зайти на сервер и открыть этот файл и сохранить его`(ctrl+s)` то после этого он начинает отображаться, а не скачиваться.

Доп информация.

Сервер `tomcat`. `Content-type` до и после `text/plain`. Размер файла не изменяется после сохранения.

Comment: [Вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105029/open-text-file-in-browser-tab-in-utf-8) попробуйте

Comment: Может быть поможет `content-disposition: inline`

Answer (score 1):

```
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>txt</extension>  
    <mime-type>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
```

Помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: вы как-нибудь упомяните что это ответ от  @Alex Belyaev. Или отметьте его как "Общий".